# Make paragraphs indent to same place

Tags: html, css, indentation

I have a bunch of months, and each month is followed by one or more text blurbs saying some news that happened then. I'm looking for a way to make all the text boxes to align to the same spot.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
      <h2 class="Date">October</h2>
      <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  </div>
<div class="container">
      <h2 class="Date">June</h2>
      <p class="info">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
  </div>
```

Here's a JS fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/530s6hqL/3/

In that fiddle my goal is to have the "Duis" and the "Lorem" be indented the same amount.

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Assign a `width` to the `.Date` elements: [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/530s6hqL/11/).

Comment: The question does not describe the desired styling as a whole and does not contain the CSS code used, only HTML code. And it’s the styling that matters here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user @David Thomas answered it with his comment. If he wants to submit it as an answer I'll switch over the correct answer to him, but what solved the problem was adding width to the .Date elements.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/x9mtw8uL/

I changed the css for the *info* class to the following:

```
.info {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 100px;
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

*margin-left* may be changed to whatever suits you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are trying to achieve is a tabular presentation, with month names in as row headers (in the first column) and some content per month as data cells. This would be most naturally and most safely achieved using an `html` table, but it can be simulated using your current markup and using CSS tables on it. An outer container is not needed for the basic table formatting, but it is the simplest way to achieve what is the desired spacing between cells (since `border-spacing` needs to be on an element with `display` value of `table` or `inline-table`). The “indentation” as such (making all paragraphs start at the same point horizontally) is achieved with the basic table formatting.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 0.5em 0.8em;
}
.container {
  display: table-row;
}
.container > h2, p.info {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
<div class="container">
          <h2 class="Date">October</h2>
          <p class="info">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    <div class="container">
          <h2 class="Date">June</h2>
          <p class="info">Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
</div>
</div>
```